# Further define a GAWK match and divide operation

Tags: regex, awk

I have some TXT files with numbers in them that I need to divide by 4.
Text-line I'm matching and changing is:-

```
scale = 23 23
```

My little GAWK file looks like this:-

```
/scale [\=] [0-9]+ [0-9]+/ {
    $3 = int($3/4)
    $4 = int($4/4) }
{print}
```

So I successfully get "scale = 5 5"

But, I have 3 more requirements, however, and would love some help...

1) the "scale" parameter should only be that following another match called "detail" on some lines above it.
 (so instead of simply matching every "scale = " it would be "detail(.....)scale = ") (any number/letter/+newline between them)

2) these values of "scale" should never be lower than 1.
 (dividing anything lower than 6 should always give a result of 1 (just changing "scale = 0" to "scale = 1" after will do))

3) values should preferably round up instead of down. 
 (so instead of 5 here from 23, it is actually 5.75 and should round up to 6 (this isn't SO important, but would be nice))

Comment: Can you give sample text input for 1) which line would `detail` come after `scale`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
awk '/detail/ { d=1 }
    d && /scale = [0-9]+ [0-9]+/ && $3>1 && $4>1 {
        $3 = $3<6 ? 1 : sprintf("%1.0f", $3/4)
        $4 = $4<5 ? 1 : sprintf("%1.0f", $4/4)
        d = 0 }
    1'
```

`sprintf` with a suitable format specifier applies rounding (see e.g. https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Round-Function.html)

The ternary operator `x ? y : z` produces `y` if `x` is true, otherwise `z`.

Notice also the minor simplifications (`=` doesn't need a backslash or a character class, and `{print}` can be shortened to just `1`).

Comment: I'm not sure if the `scale` values need to be bigger than one coming in, or going out. It should be obvious what to remove if you mean the output only.

Comment: On my MacOS Mojave, `awk 'BEGIN { printf "%.0f\n", 50/4 }' </dev/null` produces `12`. Again, see the link for details; this depends on the underlying C library.

Comment: Works perfectly for my case and luckily works great for multiple instances of detail and scale too, so thank you very much!